# Does extraposition work in "I made happy my friend who..."?

Tags: extraposition

Can we use extraposition rule in the situations like below?

"I made my friend who came here last week happy"

Can it be like this?

"I made happy my friend who came here last week"

Comment: The second sentence feels unnatural to me, though I don’t think I can say it’s *wrong*.

Comment: Happy made I my friend who came here last week.

Comment: Extraposition from NP (not Extraposition, which applies only to heavy subjects) moves heavy relative clauses away from antecedents, but it doesn't move predicates like _happy_. The transformed sentence should be _I made my friend happy who came here last week_, not the ungrammatical *_I made happy my friend who came here last week_

Comment: I imagine in a casual context you'd say something like "You know my friend who came here last week, I made him happy." or  "See my friend who came here last week, I made him happy."

Comment: Only if you are Yoda.

Comment: To me, "I made happy the friend who came here last week" sounds slightly more natural than "my friend", maybe because "the friend" expects something to specify which friend it is.

Comment: These both sound like examples from a dubious book introducing English grammar. It would be much better to rephrase completely. "A friend of mine came here last week. I made sure he enjoyed his stay." //  "My friend – the one who came here last week – really enjoyed his stay. I made sure he did" sound more natural.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is an example of shifting and not extraposition. Extraposition would require moving a constituent in such a way that it causes a discontinuity, but here there is no discontinuity. If you wanted to use extraposition, you could word it this way.

> "I made my friend happy who came here last week."

Please note that the first way you have it written is the most canonical word ordering.

See the Wikipedia articles on extraposition and shifting, linked below, for more details and examples.

- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extraposition
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_(linguistics)